# How to open multiple Chrome instances?

Tags: google-chrome

If I click with the middle mouse button on Chrome in the taskbar, it opens a new window. That's the first part of what I want (a new window with its own set of tabs), but the caching is the same as the other window.

Is there any way to open multiple instances of Chrome that don't share caching or cookies? I can do this through Incognito mode but that has various limitations that make it unacceptable.

Why would I want to do this? Different sets of accounts for different activities (eg: business1, business2, personal etc). I don't want to use profiles either, rather I'd prefer it be possible to open multiple instances of Chrome that are separate from one another entirely.

Any ideas?

Comment: Chrome allows multiple users, and you can have instances for multiple users running simultaneously. The linked Q-and-A proposes this solution.

Answer (score 2):

Practically, they kind of are separate instances because each tab is run under separate process. As for 'new windows' from an arrangement perspective and without using incognito, you can start that with right click on chrome's taskbar icon and choosing 'new window' or from its menu if you have it open already.
That does not solve your caching problem. The browsers are designed this way.

For what you want, you can:

- run it sandboxed
- run portable versions in separate folders, which should keep all things separate

Comment: These are good solutions, but it seems I need to re-download all the plugins. So I take it that each instance of Google Chrome is hard-wired to have the same cache?

Comment: Caching is done in user folders so that's why every instance of an installed version will share the cache. Yes, the plugins will have to be added for the portable version and then you should be able to copy that to how many other folders you need.